# how to implement Autocomplete( dynamic drop-down ) in Angular 2

Tags: angular, autocomplete, jquery-chosen

I want  the full code for  implementing Autocomplete( dynamic drop-down ) in Angular 2 ... Help in this regard will be very much grateful from my end ...
Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a component-writing (or component-finding) service. You are expected to do some research and attempts to solve your own problem. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Full code for Angular Material Autocomplete examples can be found at https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples. Of special interest for you are the icon buttons marked in the picture below, they are linked to the relevant resources.

[image]